# why my angular index.html name changed to index.original.html after using ng deploy for firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase-hosting, angular-universal

> Hi, I want to deploy my angular universal app in firebase earlier everything was working perfectly but now after using ng deploy my index.html page named to index.original.html inside the dist folder but my deployment is successful but I am getting page not found error.

Comment: Hi I also have the same issue, have you figured out the solution? Please share